# Test framework for web views that depend on JS rendering?

Tags: javascript, web-development, python, unit-tests

I wonder if there is a good javascript test framework that I can use, similar to Selenium, to test my web views. I have a back-end which is done with bottle, mako and python and javascript with jquery for the views.

Now I want to test the rendering and test the views and I found that scripting tests with selenium in python maybe isn't the most appripriate in this case.

Can you recommend if some framework seems best for my situation, could I use Karma, Mocha, Protractor or what are my options?

Comment: Not sure if going for a JS framework will reduce testing effort. You could try github.com/cobrateam/splinter, a layer of abstraction on top of Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nightwatchjs](http://nightwatchjs.org) is a NodeJs based end to end framework for browser based applications.